# Div desalinhadas na base

Tags: css, html5, flexbox

Galera, tenho um `h2` e um `p` dentro de uma mesma div e gostaria que os dois ficassem alinhados pela base. Inseri os seguintes atributos na div pai:

```
.banner--text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 750px;
}
```

Nas divs filho:

```
.banner--text h2 {
    text-align: end;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    max-width: 270px;
}

.banner--text p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

Só que não tem jeito de alinhar pela base, fica sempre uma pequena diferença:

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9ajE.jpg)

Alterando o `line-height` de um dos elementos eu quase cheguei a um resultado satisfatório, mas não fica 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu consegui talvez um resultado satisfatório da seguinte forma:

```html
<head>
   <style>
      body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: black;
      }
      section{
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content:space-between;
      align-items:center;
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: brown;
      }
      .div-h1{
      width: 50vw;
      }
      .div-p{
      width: 50vw;
      }
      .div-h1 h1{
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      height: 25vh;
      font-size: 3rem;
      }
      .div-p p{
      color: white;
      height: 5vh;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <section class="container">
      <div class="div-h1">
         <h1>A entidade mais beneficiente mais antiga de Caixias do Sul</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div-p">
         <p>Fundada em 13 de Abril de 1938, na época batizada Sociedade Caxiense de Apoio aos Necessitados, a SCAN passou a priorizar o atendimento aos idosos na década de 90.</p>
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS90b.png)

Acredito que o problema de alinhamento é justamente por conta da diferença entre o line-height do h1 e o parágrafo. Nesse caso aí o problema eu resolvo alinhando o height do parágrafo no item referente ao heigth do h1 de forma manual.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Experimente zerar o padding e mudar box-sizing.

padding:0;
box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).